# Selected Item Always deselect (C#)

Tags: c#, uwp

I am implementing a list box, when i select an item in list box it appears on a text block "MiniTextBlock" , but i want when text block text is changed manually or textblock text is not equal to selected item in list box then, that selected item should be deselected from list box.

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4) };
timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, object e)
{

    if(selectedItem != null && selectedItem.ToString() != MiniTextBlock.Text)
    {
        FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
};
timer.Start();
```

every thing looks correct but it is deselect even if Textblock text and selected item is same.

**Full Sample Codes**

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Name="MiniTextBlock" Text="35" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <ListBox Name="FavoritesListBox" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="36" FontSize="30"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="35" FontSize="30"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="34" FontSize="30"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4) };
    timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, object e)
    {
        var selectedItem = FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem;

        if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.ToString() != MiniTextBlock.Text)
        {
            FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Comment: Probably the fact that you set the index, results in the fact that you trigger the event again, and that `SelectedItem` now is `null`.

Comment: I think on your event change the ddl value is getting cleared. Alternatively, you can check this before your condition. if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())){if(FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() != MiniTextBLock.Text)
{
    FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}}

Comment: may be possible  because i insert it in DispatcherTimer so it will check if itemchanged in text block or not, how can i deal with it

Comment: @Deepak checking .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not binding a source to your `ListBox`, the `SelectedItem` is actually a `ListBoxItem`, not a `string`. You'll need to drill down and find the actual text like this:

```
timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, object e)
{
    var selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem;

    if (selectedItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var tb = (TextBlock)selectedItem.Content;

    if (tb.Text != MiniTextBlock.Text)
    {
        FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: In -    var tb = (TextBlock)selectedItem.Content; , "Content" is not a available or not valid

Comment: Wow ! its working now , Thank's YoU ;) actually i will use it in list box which contain a text Textblock with text binding under a data template. i make above sample fo simplyfy my question let see it will work on that

Comment: Its through an exception if i used in my actual list box(Question Updated with actual text block) looks like because of i use item template > datatamplate > textblock can you look for this

Comment: okay i am updating more it is a storage which contain all items even it app is exiting actually i use this method http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-store-listbox-items-into.html

Comment: Ok. Whatever your list is, you need to know that `SelectedItem` will be of that type. So if `ItemsSource = List<string>`, `FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem` will be of type `string`. Got it?

Comment: yes my item is string so i convert SelectedItem.ToString but can you explain with one more update answer please :(.... old answer is work if i use directly listboxitem so dont remove it also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156767/discussion-between-arpit-jain-and-laith).

Comment: i asked seprated question for my new problem

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you **trigger the event *again*** by setting `SelectedIndex` to `-1`, as a result `SelectedItem` is now `null`. Anyway, in that case a quick fix is to *guard* the `if` statement with a possible `null`:

```
var selectedItem = FavoritesListBox.SelectedItem;

if(selectedItem != null && selectedItem.ToString() != MiniTextBLock.Text)
{
    FavoritesListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: it  works but deselect item even if selected item and text block item is same

Comment: @ArpitJain: are you sure both are exactly the same. You better run a debugger and check if these are *exactly* the same. Whitespace, (upper)case, etc. can all make a difference.

Comment: exactly same because previously that item added to list box from that text block, and it is digit no chance of upper case and lower case

Comment: @ArpitJain: I would suggest to check this in the debugger. Since `MiniTextBLock` might change as well, etc.

Comment: Unable To Understand whats is happen i update my question with simple sample codes